# Error: No module name 'Custom Class' while passing a Client object in the custom class's constructor in dask

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I have been trying to write custom classes for `Preprocessing` followed by `Feature selection` and `Machine Learning` algorithms as well.

I cracked this `(preprocessing only)` using `@delayed`. But when I read from the [tutorials](https://github.com/dask/dask-tutorial/blob/master/06_distributed_advanced.ipynb) that the same can be achieved using `Client`. It caused two problems.

> Running as a script. Not as a Jupyter notebook

*First Problem:*

```
# Haven't run any scheduler or worker manually
client = Client() # Nothing passed as an argument
# Local Cluster is not working;
Error:... 
       if __name__=='__main__': 
            freeze_support()
      ...
```

I tried the same in Jupyter Notebook, without running any scheduler or workers in different terminals. **It worked!!**

Now, I triggered 3 terminals with 1 scheduler and 2 workers and changed it to `Client('IP')` in the script. **Error resolved, any reason for this behavior.**

*Second Problem:*

The error mentioned in the title of the question. Passed the `client = Client('IP')` as the argument to the constructor and used `self.client.submit` things to the cluster. But failed with the error message

> Error: No module name 'diya_info'

Here's the code:

main.py

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from diya_info import Diya_Info
import time
# from dask import delayed
from dask.distributed import Client

df = dd.read_csv(
    '/Users/asifali/workspace/playground/flask/yellow_tripdata_2015- 01.csv')

# df = delayed(df.fillna(0.3))
# df = df.compute()

client = Client('192.168.0.129:8786')

X = df.drop('payment_type', axis=1).copy()
y = df['payment_type']


Instance = Diya_Info(X, y, client)
s = time.ctime(int(time.time()))
print(s)


Instance = Instance.fit(X, y)


e = time.ctime(int(time.time()))
print(e)
# print((e-s) % 60, ' secs')
```

diya_info.py

```
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator
from dask.multiprocessing import get
from dask import delayed, compute


class Diya_Info(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, X, y, client):
        assert X is not None, 'X can\'t be None'
        assert type(X).__name__ == 'DataFrame', 'X not of type DataFrame'
        assert y is not None, 'y can\'t be None'
        assert type(y).__name__ == 'Series', 'y not of type Series'

        self.client = client

    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.X = X
        self.y = y
        # X_status = self.has_null(self.X)
        # y_status = self.has_null(self.y)
        # X_len = self.get_len(self.X)
        # y_len = self.get_len(self.y)
        X_status = self.client.submit(self.has_null, self.X)
        y_status = self.client.submit(self.has_null, self.y)
        X_len = self.client.submit(self.get_len, self.X)
        y_len = self.client.submit(self.get_len, self.y)
        # X_null, y_null, X_length, y_length
        X_null, y_null, X_length, y_length = self.client.gather(
        [X_status, y_status, X_len, y_len])

        assert X_null == False, 'X contains some columns with null/NaN values'
        assert y_null == False, 'y contains some columns with null/NaN values'
        assert X_length == y_length, 'Shape mismatch, X and y are of different length'
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X

    @staticmethod
    # @delayed
    def has_null(df):
        return df.isnull().values.any()

    @staticmethod
    # @delayed
    def get_len(df):
        return len(df)
```

Here's the full stacktrace:

```
Sat Aug 11 13:29:08 2018
distributed.utils - ERROR - No module named 'diya_info'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 238, in f
    result[0] = yield make_coro()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1315, in _gather
    traceback)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 692, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/protocol/pickle.py", line 59, in loads
    return pickle.loads(x)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'diya_info'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "notebook/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    Instance = Instance.fit(X, y)
  File "/Users/asifali/workspace/pythonProjects/ML-engine-DataX/pre-processing/notebook/diya_info.py", line 28, in fit
    X_status, y_status, X_len, y_len)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 2170, in compute
    result = self.gather(futures)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1437, in gather
    asynchronous=asynchronous)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 592, in sync
    return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 254, in sync
    six.reraise(*error[0])
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 238, in f
    result[0] = yield make_coro()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1315, in _gather
    traceback)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 692, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/protocol/pickle.py", line 59, in loads
    return pickle.loads(x)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'diya_info'
```

If I uncomment the `@delayed` and few more comments it works. But how to make it work by passing in the `client` as an argument.
Idea is to use the same client for all the libs I'm trying to write.

**UPDATE 1:**
I fixed the `second problem` by removing the `@staticmethod` decorators and placing the functions in the `fit closure`. **But what's wrong with the `@staticmethod`, these decorators are meant for non-self related stuff, right?**

Here's the `diya_info.py`:

```
...
def fit(self, X, y):
   self.X = X
   self.y = y

   # function removed from @staticmethod
   def has_null(df): return df.isnull().values.any()
   # function removed from @staticmethod
   def get_len(df): return len(df)

   X_status = self.client.submit(has_null, self.X)
   y_status = self.client.submit(has_null, self.y)
...
```

Is there a way to do it with `@staticmethod`. I don't feel good with the way I have solved this issue. Still no clue about `Problem 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'diya_info'
```

This means that while your client has access to this module, your workers do not.  A simple way to resolve this would be to upload your script to your workers.

```
client.upload_file('diya_info.py')
```

But in general it's on you to ensure that your workers and clients all have the same software environment